# How to update variable from another file Python

Tags: python, variables, pygame

I call variable from another file and that variable always changes the value (value is int) and I try to print that variable in this file but the value in a variable does not change they get just first value and not update if it changes.

It is UI and uses Lib Pygame I use data from the image processing section, image processing section save some data in variable type int (assume that variable is AJ) and then I pick AJ to use in GUI
First file

```
from second_file import AJ

    if AJ == 1:
        draw_text('SNACK', font, (200, 220, 0), screen, 1130, 660)
    elif AJ == 2:
        draw_text('CAN', font, (200, 220, 0), screen, 1130, 660)
    elif AJ == 3:
        draw_text('BOTTLE', font, (200, 220, 0), screen, 1130, 660)
```

**example** variable starts at 3, this file always draw_text  'BOTTLE'  Although variable change value to 1 but this file did not get that value I must run code again...

Comment: Are you updating the code in the imported file while this script is running?

Comment: Its a little hard to understand, maybe you could post more code? like how you change the variable?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille something like that

Comment: @TheBigKahuna I post more describe Is it okay I don't know how to describe it...

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
from double_test import variable
blah(variable)
```

with

```
import double_test
blah(double_text.variable)
```

Also modules are only loaded once in python, if you modified the module on file and your want to see the new values, you'll also need to `reload()` the module.